# export to CSV percentage formatting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, formatting, export

Having an issue with the formatting of the percentages in an exported CSV file.

Here is the process that grabs the data and sends it back to JQuery to be exported:

```
<?php
  include('include/sessions.php');

  $date_begin = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date_begin']));
  $date_end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date_end']));

  $sql = "SELECT table1.services, table1.port
          sum(case when TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,table2.berth,table1.performance) <= -12 then 0 else 1 end) ON_TIME,
          count(table1.port) TTL_CALLS,
          round((sum(case when TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,table2.berth,table1.performance) <= -12 then 0 else 1 end)/count(table1.port))*100,1) as ON_TIME_PCT
          FROM
            table1
          Left Outer Join table2 ON table1.voyage = table2.voyage AND table1.port = table2.port
          WHERE
            date( table1.performance ) >= '$date_begin' AND
            date( table1.performance ) <= '$date_end'";

  $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

  $out = array();
  while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    $out[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($out);
  
?>
```

The field I am referring to is ON_TIME_PCT.

Using the above, when running the query in the dB itself, the results of the query for the field in reference can vary between 100.0 or 50.0.

When the data is exported, the cells initially look like 100 or 50.

When changing the format in Excel to show the full percentage, the numbers look like 10000% or 5000%.

I am not sure why that is happening.

Here is the code that I am using to export to CSV:

```
$('#byPortService').on('click', function(){

  var date_begin = $('#date_begin').val();
  var date_end = $('#date_end').val();

  $.post('api/byPortService.php', {date_begin:date_begin,date_end:date_end}, function(data){
    JSONToCSVConvertor(data, "BY PORT SERVICE REPORT - DATE RANGE: "+date_begin+" - "+date_end+"", true);
  });
});
```

Here is the JSONToCSVConvertor function:

```
function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel){
  var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;
  var CSV = '';
  CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\n';
  if (ShowLabel) {
    var row = "";
    for (var index in arrData[0]) {
      row += index + ',';
    }
    row = row.slice(0, -1);
    CSV += row + '\r\n';
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
    var row = "";
    for (var index in arrData[i]) {
      row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
    }
    row.slice(0, row.length - 1);
    CSV += row + '\r\n';
   }
   if (CSV == '') {
     alert("Invalid data");
     retirn;
   }
   var fileName = ReportTitle.replace(/ /g,"_");
   var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);
   var link = document.createElement("a");
   link.href = uri;
   link.style = "visibility:hidden";
   link.download = fileName + ".csv";
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   link.click();
   document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Is there any way that I can export the percentages so that they retain the decimal?

I don't want the user to have to manually do it on the Excel side.

Comment: You will need to divide the values by 100. Excel converts it to a percentage and `1` is `100%` and `.5` is `50%`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - are you referring to this part:  count(table1.port))*100,1)

Comment: `1` in Excel is `100%`. `0.5` is `50%`, etc

Comment: I didn't look through all of the code but you need to divide the result.

Comment: I no longer see the comment, but someone suggested removing *100, which I did, and that seemed to work.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by changing this line:

```
round((sum(case when TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,table2.berth,table1.performance) <= -12 then 0 else 1 end)/count(table1.port))*100,1) as ON_TIME_PCT
```

To this:

```
concat(round((sum(case when TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,table2.berth,table1.performance) <= -12 then 0 else 1 end)/count(table1.port))*100,0),'%') as ON_TIME_PCT
```

And now the fields are showing 100% or 50% even after formatting Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentionned in comments, make sure the values are between `0` and `1`.

To keep a certain amount of decimal in PHP, use [number_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
<?php
$number = 0.5;
formatted number = number_format($number, 2);  // 0.50
?>
```

Comment: How would I apply that in the query?

Comment: Unsure what the json structure is. can you post a sample (2~3 lines) ?